# What is default autoscrolling interval and step?

Tags: winforms, winapi, scroll, custom-controls

I'm writing custom tree control from scratch and I've yet implemented most of default behaviors of Windows control. My last change involved adding so called autoscroll feature: if you start making a rectangular selection and drag mouse below or above control, it starts to scroll automatically, such that you can select more elements than are currently visible.

I would like my control to behave as similar to other Windows controls as possible, so my question is: is the automatic scroll interval and scroll step (eg. pixels to be scrolled) defined somewhere in the WinAPI? Are there different scrolling speeds for different distances from the control bounds and if so, are they defined somewhere as well?

Comment: No, nothing for that in SystemParametersInfo().  And pretty inconsistent because of that.